# How to view (the same) data (of User) in UserProfile in Django

Tags: python, django, authentication, django-admin

So I've got this situation.

-models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone
from autoslug import AutoSlugField
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    website = models.URLField(blank=True)
    picture = models.ImageField(upload_to='profile_images', blank=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.user.username
```

-forms.py

```
from django import forms
from django.forms import ModelForm
from tentagarden.models import UserProfile
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from parsley.decorators import parsleyfy

@parsleyfy
class UserForm(forms.ModelForm):
    password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput())

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('username', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'password')

class UserProfileForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = UserProfile
        fields = ('website', 'picture')
```

-views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response, render, redirect
from django.template import RequestContext
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect, HttpResponse
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login, logout
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required

from tentagarden.forms import UserForm, UserProfileForm

def home(request):
    context = RequestContext(request)

    registered = False

    if request.method == 'POST':
        user_form = UserForm(data=request.POST)
        profile_form = UserProfileForm(data=request.POST)

        if user_form.is_valid() and profile_form.is_valid():
            user = user_form.save()

            user.set_password(user.password)
            user.save()

            profile = profile_form.save(commit=False)
            profile.user = user

            if 'picture' in request.FILES:
                profile.picture = request.FILES['picture']

            profile.save()

            registered = True

        else:
            print user_form.errors, profile_form.errors

    else:
        user_form = UserForm()
        profile_form = UserProfileForm()

    return render_to_response(
            'tentagarden/home.html',
            {'user_form': user_form, 'profile_form': profile_form, 'registered': registered},
            context)
```

-admin.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import File, Post, UserProfile

admin.site.register(File)
admin.site.register(Post)
admin.site.register(UserProfile)
```

And I'd like to have the User data (so First name, Last name and Email) visualized in "User profiles" (in the Admin page), other than in "Users" only.
What should I do?

Thank you!

Comment: Why have you posted all this code if you're just interested in the admin? And why haven't you posted the actually relevant code, admin.py?

Comment: Because I'm a noob, and I'm going to post it now, sorry :-\

Comment: What do you mean exactly by  visualized in "User profiles" (in the Admin page), other than in "Users" only? Do you want 3 separate columns for it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put this is in your admin.py

```
class UserProfileAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('email', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'website')
    search_fields = ('user__username', 'user__first_name', 'user__last_name', 'user__email')
    # list_filter = ('some_field_to_filter')
    readonly_fields = ('email', 'first_name', 'last_name')

    def email(self, obj):
        return obj.user.email
    def first_name(self, obj):
        return obj.user.first_name
    def last_name(self, obj):
        return obj.user.last_name

admin.site.register(UserProfile, UserProfileAdmin)
```

Use [fieldsets](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.fieldsets) to control the order of displayed fields in edit view.

Comment: This is almost perfect, thanks!
The only other thing left is that I'd like to view the Email, First name and Last name fields also when I click to see the details of the user. Is that possible?

Comment: you mean in edit view ? where you get all the details of profile ?

Comment: Updated the answer to do that.

Comment: Yes! Fantastic! Thank you very much :)